# .tcl file not running

Tags: tcl

I have installed ns2 on ubuntu 12.04. when I am trying to run .tcl file following error is showing up:

```
ajay@ajay-Inspiron-535s:~$ cd ajay
ajay@ajay-Inspiron-535s:~/ajay$ ns old.tcl
couldn't read file "old.tcl": no such file or directory
```

Comment: "couldn't read file "old.tcl": no such file or directory" you sure the file exist?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to run it or open it? A tcl file is a script and running it equates to running the contents of the script, while opening it equates to viewing its contents only.
You will have to install a tcl library first.
You can download the installer from ActiveState Tcl.
After installation, you should be able to run the script
Depending on your script, you may not be able to run/execute it even after downloading and installing from ActiveTcl, and may receive errors like can't find package .... 
This is because the ActiveState installation is only a bare bones Tcl interpreter. 
If you encounter this problem, get a command prompt and type teapot update-self and, when this completes, teaport update. (The second command will take quite a long time.) 
Even this may not fix things.